# Workflow with 3 levels of approvals (without taskforms) - Best way to implement

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have a List Form which is filled by employee and on submitting it has to go through three levels of approvals. Approval section(Approver Name, Date, Approved/Rejected) for each of these members is in the list form.

When the employee submits the form mail should go to first approver and he has to take action (approved/rejected) and then mail should go to second approver and so on.

I thought of 2 ways of doing this and I am not sure which one would be better.(SharePoint 2013 Workflow)

1) Wait for the field change (trigger workflow on item create)

2) Set stages(Empcompleted, firstlevelcompleted and so on) and create workflow based on these stages (trigger workflow on item create and edit)

I am not sure if Wait action works fine or if I will face any problems in long run.

Comment: I had similar task. What you didn't mention in your question is, What will happen if second or third approver rejects item? Will workflow be finished or will it loop and go to the beginning to the first approver?

Comment: In my case, Workflow has to continue to the next step even if one of the approver is not approving it

Answer (score 1):

How will item be sent to the 2nd or 3rd approver if your WF is triggered only on item created :? It is unclear, but as I mentioned I've created similar WF and I made it with triggering WF on item create/edit. On create is for 1st approver and On edit is for the 2nd and 3rd ones.

You don't need wait option. What you need is enough columns to satisfy all possibilities/options and IF loops. Exp. extra columns **Approver (1, 2, 3 (separately)) approved** YES/NO.
So If Approver 1 is empty send mail to 1st; If 2 and 3 are empty and 1st is not empty, send mail to 2nd; If 3rd is empty and 1st and 2nd are not empty send mail to 3rd.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did a similar workflow but instead set stages EmpSubmitted,Approver1Completed etc and triggered workflow on New and Create. Regarding "How will item be sent to the 2nd or 3rd approver if your WF is triggered only on item created :?" My plan was to trigger workflow on Item create if I use 'Wait for field change'.

Answer (score 0):

We do a lot of these. I've never liked the 'waiting for' in workflows - I know they 'dehydrate' and are stored in the DB, but I've never trusted workflows that stick around.
We use a status field that has different options, like

```
    Ready for Approval
    Approval 1 Complete
    Approval 2 Complete
    Approval 3 Complete
```

but more complex. We have a change workflow that tests for the change in the status field (by checking another hidden field I add to the list), and if one of those status' is selected, it emails the next person, with instructions to 'Set xxxx Complete' status. It then changes my hidden field to the value of the Status field so the email won't go out again.
Workflow done.

When the next approver changes the status, the next email goes out.

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint 3 level workflow Step by step 
https://youtu.be/xblIK7Ys5ig

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)